CPLEX: solve() returns false but getCplexStatus() shows Optimal — what's causing this?
I have a problem that I don't understand how this is possible.
This is a snapshot of the code:
IloNumVarArray variables;

IloEnv environment;
  
if(!cplex.solve()) {
  
  IloCplex::CplexStatus cplexStatus = cplex.getCplexStatus();

  IloAlgorithm::Status status = cplex.getStatus();
        
  printf("status: %d %d\n", cplexStatus, status);

}

IloNumArray values(environment);
  
cplex.getValues(values, variables);

The strange thing is that the program occasionally prints
“status: 1 1”
which respectively are: CplexStatus::CPX_STAT_OPTIMAL and Status::Feasible
why does cplex.solve() return false while cplex.getCplexStatus() returns that it found an easible solution and cplex.getStatus()
returns that it found a feasible solution?
If I force the program to call cplex.getValues(), ignoring the return value of cplex.solve() in these cases, the call to cplex.getValues() generates a running exception

Have you tried checking if the optimal "solution" found by Cplex is in fact correct when back substituted into your original equations? Sometimes algorithms get stuck or due to rounding errors report inconsistent solved/not solved status depending on exactly how they measure success. Having a pole in the domain of the solution for example is one way that these things can go haywire. Without knowing what optimisation problem and constraints Cplex has been asked to solve it is pure speculation.
